# Importar uma lista para outro Form C#

Tags: c#, winforms, lista

Não sei importar uma lista para um outro `form`, se alguém puder me ajudar. O código da primeira `form` está assim: Note que eu quero Transportar a `ListaFornecedores` para a `Form` `FrmNovoProduto`. Como Disse não sei se é assim que se faz.

```
public partial class FrmCadastrarProduto : Form
{
    List<Produtos> oRetorno = new List<Produtos>();
    List<Fornecedores> ListaFornecedores = new List<Fornecedores>();
    public FrmCadastrarProduto()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void novoProdutoToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CarregaFornecedores();
        FrmNovoProduto oFrmNovoProduto = new FrmNovoProduto(ListaFornecedores);
        oFrmNovoProduto.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

A form que receberá a lista esta assim:

```
public partial class FrmNovoProduto : Form
{
    private static List<Rodolfo.Fornecedores> Lista;
    public FrmNovoProduto(Lista)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public FrmNovoProduto()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void FrmNovoProduto_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Como faço isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Falta uns detalhes no `FrmNovoProduto`

> 1 - A lista não precisa ter o modificador `static` (nesse contexto não seria válido)
>
> 2 - No `Construtor` `FrmNovoProduto` falta colocar o tipo que vai ser passado no caso `List<Rodolfo.Fornecedores>`
>
> 3 - Faltou passar o valor para `Lista` que no caso é `Lista = lista;`
>
> 4 - Agora você pode usar essa variável no seu projeto ...

Observe mudanças nesse código:

```
public partial class FrmNovoProduto : Form
{
    private List<Rodolfo.Fornecedores> Lista;
    public FrmNovoProduto(List<Rodolfo.Fornecedores> lista)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Lista = lista;
    }
    public FrmNovoProduto()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void FrmNovoProduto_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         //pode utilizar a variavel Lista
    }
}
```

No código `FrmCadastrarProduto` parece não precisa de modificação visto que eu imagino que `CarregaFornecedores();` carrega os fornecedores e `ListaFornecedores` tem os valores que foram carregados.

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class FrmCadastrarProduto : Form
{
    List<Produtos> oRetorno = new List<Produtos>();
    List<Fornecedores> ListaFornecedores = new List<Fornecedores>();
    public FrmCadastrarProduto()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void novoProdutoToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CarregaFornecedores();
        FrmNovoProduto oFrmNovoProduto = new FrmNovoProduto(ListaFornecedores);
        oFrmNovoProduto.ShowDialog();
    }
}

public partial class FrmNovoProduto : Form
{
    List<Rodolfo.Fornecedores> Lista = null;

    public FrmNovoProduto(List<Fornecedores> lista)
    {
        Lista = lista;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public FrmNovoProduto()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void FrmNovoProduto_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```